# Merging some objects by iterating through an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-merge, arrayobject

I have the following array

```
recipe = [
{ 
   id: "abc123", en: {title: "", description: ""}, es: {titleES: "", descriptionES: ""}
},
{ 
   id: "abc128", en: {title: "", description: ""}, es: {titleES: "", descriptionES: ""}
},
{ 
   id: "abc135", en: {title: "", description: ""}, es: {titleES: "", descriptionES: ""}
}
]
```

and I want to create a new array with 1 object that includes the objects "id" and "en" like this

```
newArray = [
{ 
   id: "abc123", title: "", description: ""
},
{ 
   id: "abc128", title: "", description: ""
},
{ 
   id: "abc135", title: "", description: ""
}
]
```

I tried the following but does not seem to work correctly

```
const dataList = [];
      for (let idx in recipe) {        
        dataList.push({...recipe[idx].id, ...recipeES[idx].all });
        
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traverse the array using array map method and make your object.

```js
const recipe = [
  {
    id: 'abc123',
    en: { title: '', description: '' },
    es: { titleES: '', descriptionES: '' },
  },
  {
    id: 'abc128',
    en: { title: '', description: '' },
    es: { titleES: '', descriptionES: '' },
  },
  {
    id: 'abc135',
    en: { title: '', description: '' },
    es: { titleES: '', descriptionES: '' },
  },
];
const ret = recipe.map((x) => {
  const obj = { id: x.id, ...x.en };
  return obj;
});
console.log(ret);
```